# How to get custom intent slot values using handlerInput in ASK-SDK v2

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm creating a basic calculator skill using ASK-SDK v2. I'm not sure how to get the slot values provided by the user into the Lambda code with the new version. I was able to make it work with the older version.

Conversation
User: Open calculate
Alexa: You can ask me to add, subtract, multiply and divide
User: Add two and three
Alexa: Sum of 2 and 3 is 5

Below is my IntentSchema

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "calculate",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AddIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "numA",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "numB",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "Sum of {numA} and {numB}",
                        "add {numA} and {numB}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "SubIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "numA",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "numB",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "difference between {numA} and {numB}",
                        "subtract {numA} from {numB}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "ProductIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "numA",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "numB",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "multiply {numA} and {numB}",
                        "product of {numA} and {numB}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "DivideIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "numA",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "numB",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "divide {numB} by {numA}",
                        "divide {numA} by {numB}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "ExponentialIntent",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "numA",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "numB",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "numC",
                            "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "{numA} raised to the power of {numB} by {numC}",
                        "{numA} raised to the power {numB}"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}
```

I'm adding the addintenthandler here. Please tell me if the approach I'm using to get the slot values from the intent is correct or if I should use sessionattributes

```
const AddIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AddIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        var output1 = "";
        var num1 = handlerInput.resuestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.numA.value;
        var num2 = handlerInput.resuestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.numB.value;
        if((num1)&&(num2)){
            output1 = 'The sum of ' +num1+ ' and ' +num2+ ' is ' + (num1+num2);
        }
        else {
            output1 = 'Enter valid number';
        }
        const speechText = output1;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

Alexa responds with "Unable to process requested skill response"
Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: there are now built-in functions in the SDK for this:
Alexa.getSlotValue() (returns the string value) and getSlot() (returns Slot object)
Alexa.getSlotValue(handlerInput.requestEnvelope, "someSlotName")

Old answer:
You have a typo, `resuestEnvelope` should be `requestEnvelope`. In any case I have created exactly the same skill, a calculator (in Spanish but it's basically the same thing) and I use a helper function called `getSlotValues()` which I encourage you to reuse. It will also work great when you have to capture custom slots (which are processed differently because the entity resolution structure is different):

https://github.com/germanviscuso/skill-sample-nodejs-mycalculator

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It was a careless mistake. I'll definitely try out the getSlotValues() method. I still get an error though, just with the add intent. When I ask Alexa to add two and three. She replies with "Sum of 2 and 3 is 23". The other intents are working fine. I can't figure out how the logic is wrong just for addition.

Comment: You're adding strings! If you do: "2" + "3", that equals "23" (it results in a concatenation). You need to convert the values to numbers before adding them

Comment: Nowadays I only found these in the docs: `Alexa.getSlotValue()` (returns the string value) and `getSlot()` (returns Slot object) . Usual usage `Alexa.getSlotValue(handlerInput.requestEnvelope, "someSlotName")`